# Lista com registros repetidos via Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

estou tentando realizar uma consulta simples com LINQ, e o código abaixo está me retornando registros repetidos nas 5 primeiras linhas da lista.

```
var teste = (from p in db.VW_PAGAMENTO_RECEBIDO where p.ID_Pessoa == 23 select p).ToList();
```

Quando eu executo o script SQL no SQL Manager, os registros são exibidos corretamente (conforme imagem abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que o código do arquivo está diferente em todos os registros através do SqlManager. Porém, quando executo via LINQ, os 5 primeiros registros exibem os dados repedidos, iguais o primeiro.

Comment: Poderia postar o seu model `VW_PAGAMENTO_RECEBIDO`?

Comment: Você esta apontando o webconfig para o mesmo banco?

Comment: Sim estou apontando para o mesmo webconfig @DotNet

Comment: Tente var teste = (from p in db.VW_PAGAMENTO_RECEBIDO
                                         where p.ID_Pessoa == 23
                                         select new { p }
                                         ).ToList();

Comment: O ideal seria você capturar a query sql gerada no linq e ver o que foi criado.